# MySQL order by field, end with non-listed items

Tags: mysql

I am using a large MySQL query and I need to sort it by a set of `id`

This is my `order by` clause: `ORDER BY FIELD(plt_id.id, '82', '81', '78', '84', '86', '87')`

Works fantastic... but the MySQL rows starts with those `id` that are not listed. And I need the listed `id` first.

Any suggestions how to start with the `id` that ere listed in `ORDER BY FIELD(plt_id.id, '82', '81', '78', '84', '86', '87')` and after that all the rows that were not listed?

Comment: This may be useful: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109120/how-does-order-by-field-in-mysql-work-internally

Comment: Try to use DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to do it is to reverse the order of the ids listed inside the function `FIELD()` and sort descending:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(plt_id.id, '87', '86', '84', '78', '81', '82') DESC
```

For all the ids that don't exist in the list, `FIELD()` returns `0` so they will be sorted last.

Comment: Good point. I tried to add `DESC`and that did not work, but reversing the order in combination with that was the best solution!